# Java коллекции, подскажите правильный выбор коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, click, координаты

Привет всем, у меня задача состоит в том что нужно хранить где либо координаты клика мышки, притом что координаты не могут повторятся , один клик равен Х и У координате. Решил хранить данные таким способом :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал писать код, хотелось бы что б подобным  макаром работало, но не работает так:

```
ArrayList coordsContainer = new ArrayList();
сoordsContainer.add(new LinkedHashMap().put(12345,54321));
сoordsContainer.add(new LinkedHashMap().put(10,15));
System.out.println(coordsContainer.get(1));
```

Зато работает так:

```
ArrayList coordsContainer = new ArrayList();
LinkedHashMap collectionMapXY = new LinkedHashMap();
collectionMapXY.put(101010,202020);
coordsContainer.add(collectionMapXY);
System.out.println(coordsContainer.get(0));
```

Но не удобно ведь для каждого клика, создавать новый именованный экземпляр класса, я вот про эту строчку:

```
LinkedHashMap collectionMapXY = new LinkedHashMap();
```

Может я не правильно выбрал стратегию хранения не повторяющихся кликов мышки, подскажите как правильно это делается? Скажу сразу LinkedHashSet мне не устраивает ибо там нельзя обратится к елементу по индексу(Я думаю удобней будет отдельный метод написать который будет проверять на не повторение значений в Коллекции чем использовать не удобный LinkedHashSet )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс для хранения клика:

```
public class Click {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Click(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return x * 31 + y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof Click) {
            Click o = (Click) obj;
            return x == o.x && y == o.y;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Множество кликов:

```
Set<Click> set = new HashSet<>();
List<Click> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Добавляем клик:

```
Click click = new Click(123, 456);
if (!set.contains(click)) {
     set.add(click); // для быстрой проверки существования
     list.add(click); // для обращения по индексу
}
```

Примечание. Есть такая структура [Декартово_дерево](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE), которая позволяет использовать составной ключ. В данном случае оно идеально подходит. Но наверное, вам это сложно и не нужно.